# Importing an adjacency matrix (csv) containing strings and floats in R

Tags: r, csv, matrix, ggplot2

I have a co-occurrence adjacency matrix like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/matrix_added_cats.csv

Where rows and columns may contain strings with special characters ("(", "-", " ", etc.)

When I import this data into R to visualize it with `ggplot2`, I do this:

```
myData <- read.csv("/matrix_added_cats.csv")
```

Which returns:

```
                Name  NGO Gov..institutions Industry..farming. Industry..mining. Academia.research Aboriginal.groups
1                NGO 0.00              0.00                  0              0.00              0.01              0.00
2  Gov. institutions 0.00              0.01                  0              0.04              0.03              0.01
3 Industry (farming) 0.00              0.00                  0              0.00              0.00              0.00
4  Industry (mining) 0.00              0.04                  0              0.10              0.25              0.07
5  Academia/research 0.01              0.03                  0              0.25              0.36              0.10
6  Aboriginal groups 0.00              0.01                  0              0.07              0.10              0.02
```

We see that the names of columns containing float values are not the same, proper, strings as before. Which leads, I think, to several issues in my `ggplot2` visualization:

```
library(reshape)
dat <- melt(myData)
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(9, "Spectral")), space="Lab")

zp1 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x = variable, y = Name, fill = value))
zp1 <- zp1 + geom_tile()
zp1 <- zp1 + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100),trans = "reverse")
zp1 <- zp1 + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))
zp1 <- zp1 + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))
zp1 <- zp1 + coord_equal()
zp1 <- zp1 + theme_bw() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
print(zp1)
```

[image]

1) For a co-occurrence matrix to make sense, rows and columns should be in the same order (so that the same row/columns elements meet on the diagonal), but for some reason, Ggplot2 orders them differently. Could it be because strings are different between row and columns since import?

2) the specials characters are replaced by "..", which looks really bad.

Is there a way to fix these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the argument `check.names = FALSE` in `read.csv` to suppress the replacement of special characters in the column names.

```
myData <- read.csv("/matrix_added_cats.csv", check.names = FALSE)

names(myData)
# [1] "Name"               "NGO"                "Gov. institutions"  "Industry (farming)"
# [5] "Industry (mining)"  "Academia/research"  "Aboriginal groups"
```